# Plotting GAMM model results with package gratia

Tags: plot, response, gam

Is there a way to produce plots with gratia that have the y-axis on the response variable scale similar to the scale="response" visreg function? I know scale is already an option for the y-axis in gratia, but just for axis range and not transforming the variable.

Thinking of something like:

draw(mymodel, type="response")?

Answer (score 1):

This is a current feature request for the package: https://github.com/gavinsimpson/gratia/issues/79

If I ever surface from creating content for two new courses this semester adding this is a top priority for me.

Currently the best I can suggest is to evaluate the smooth using `evaluate_smooth()`, then use `mutate()` to apply the inverse of the link function to the estimated value and the confidence interval, and then use the `draw()` method for those objects to produce the plot, with *cowplot* or *patchwork* to plot multiple plots on a single page/device.

Comment: Thanks Gavin. Good to confirm I was not overlooking it. Will try your suggestion and post my answer here if I come up with something that works in the interim.

Appreciate all your helpful comments and tutorials on the subject. I have found them very helpful learing about GAMs.

Comment: Although it looks like Gavin is still improving the implementation, based on the current commits the following appears to work:  `draw(evaluate_smooth(mymodel, "s(var1)"), fun = inv_link(mymodel))`.